# Is there a word to use in business setting that is not as intense as "focus"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, vocabulary, business-language

Is there a word to use in business setting that is not as intense as "focus"?

I am trying to communicate in a header/subject line that a meeting will include discussing a specific topic, but I also want to communicate, in the same header/subject line, that the meeting might not focus exclusively on the specific topic because we may or may not discuss at least one other topic.

For example, I am trying to say "Meeting [INSERT WORD THAT IS NOT AS INTENSE AS "FOCUS"] on [INSERT SPECIFIC TOPIC]".

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I would go with *cover*

Comment: Focus in not too intense IMHO

Comment: "addressing" is another word .. with a flavor of aiming for some resolution .  However, whether focus, cover or addressing, or others, to some degree if you only mention one item, unless you use some word like "including" or "as well as normal business" or somthing there is an implication that the meeting is "focused" on the one item alone .. in my opinion at least

Comment: "Weekly staff meeting including discussion of parking spot allocation" ?

Comment: so you want to hammer topic A but avoid alarming the parties to the issue?

Comment: "Meeting **re** [TOPIC], **etc.**" If you don't like the Latin "re" you can just use "on" or "about".

Answer (score 1):

concerning   [freedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/concerning)

> "Meeting **concerning** X and time permitting Y and Z"

or

> "Meeting **concerning** X and time permitting other business"

Comment: The operative word here is “primarily”.  Whether the meeting *concerns* primarily X or *focuses* primarily on X doesn’t really matter.

Comment: @Jim seeking your advice: Meeting concerning X and time permitting, Y and Z"  OR  Meeting concerning X and other usual business.

Comment: Dunno, are Y and Z “other usual business” or are they just other topics to be covered, time permitting?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest "re" or "regarding". [Collins Thesaurus](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Re) (via thefreedictionaries.com) provides an entry for "re":

> preposition concerning, about, regarding, respecting, with regard to, on the subject of, in respect of, with reference to, apropos, anent (Scot.) Re: household insurance.

I’ve always taken "Re:" to be an abbreviation of "regarding".

Answer (score 0):

"regarding,""concerning", "re' with or without a colon or stop, are all very old-fashioned management-speak, and have been ridiculed as such, rightly, in works such as Fowler for many years.

Just use plain English: meeting to discuss [topic].